# What led to Takako's injuries?

Tags: another

When Akazawa hears Takako scream, she rushes to their room to find the sheets cut up and bloody, yet she shows up later on bloodied but fine (apart from being almost insane). Who or what caused these injuries?

Comment: Which episode is this and approximate timing?

Comment: @user1306322 I don't know exactly which episode but the whole incident is near the end when the class goes to that retreat with the mountain shrine in an attempt to avoid the Calamity like a previous class did